# How does one construct a zero morphism if given a zero object in a category?

Tags: category-theory

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_morphism#Related_concepts) defines it as the composition $g\circ f$. I'm confused about how to prove this is a zero morphism.

I'm also confused by when it is said that every category with a zero object is a category with zero morphisms given by the composition, do you have to show $g \circ f$ a left and right zero morphism, or do we have to show $C$ is a category with zero morphisms, which is different, I think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To each object $X$ we assign a special morphism $f_X : X \rightarrow 0$ defined as the only such morphism, and another special morphisms $g_X : 0 \rightarrow X$ which is also the only such morphism.

For each pair of objects $X$ and $Y$, we define $0_{X,Y} = g_Y \circ f_X$.

Now just prove that $\varphi \circ 0_{X,Y} = 0_{X,Z}$ and $0_{Y,Z} \circ \psi = 0_{X,Z}$ for all morphisms $\varphi :Y \rightarrow Z$ and $\psi : X \rightarrow Y$.

Comment: Ok, we have to show $C$ is a category with zero morphisms. I've done that now, thanks.

Comment: I just tried to prove $\varphi \circ 0_{X,Y} = 0_{X,Z}$ but got stuck on the bit showing $\varphi \circ 0: 0 \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z = 0: 0 \rightarrow Z$. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: @goblin, I think I could solve it, but this statements are only true in a pre-additive category right?